# Bootstrap Media Queries Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright guys

I am in need of someone that has got knowledge with Bootstrap Media Queries please...  I am having a few issues which is giving me a headache to solve...

I am try to make the following word press page: https://optimizepressplus.com/instruct-membership-course-page/ into a HTML page: http://unlockingblueprints.com/templates/responsive/membership-course-page.html

I am trying to make it work exactly the same but for some reason some of the actual media queries does not work even though it's coded....

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: you have jQuery error on the page have you tried to fix that first to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors

```
`Error: Element title must not be empty.
From line 6, column 12; to line 6, column 19
<title></title>`

`Warning: Consider avoiding viewport values that prevent users from resizing documents.
From line 13, column 5; to line 13, column 107
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no name='viewport'>`
```

Use 
    `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Or
     `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`